# How to install a python program using setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I am trying to install `labelImg` using [`setup.py`](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg/blob/master/setup.py). I run the command:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

to install it and everything seemed to be fine. Unfortunately when I tried to execute the program (just tried `labelImg &`) got an import error:

> ImportError: No module named 'resources'

So, I was wondering if I did something wrong or if there something I could do to fix it. My first thought is to provide an absolute import path to `resources` (and to the following `libs` imports) but that does not seem the right thing to do. Also it might work for a small project but it's obvious out of reach for a big one.

The [git repo](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg#ubuntu-linux) seem to imply that I should run it via python, but why then a `setup.py` exists?

I know I can use the program via `python` or even install it via PyPI but I am not interested in that.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions?

Comment: Yes I did. I can run the program via `python3` just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The **labelImg** project depends on other libraries to work such as **pyqt5-dev-tools** and **lxml**.

If you check their [documentation](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg#ubuntu-linux), first you have to install **pyqt5-dev-tools:**

```
 sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools
```

Then install **lxml**:

```
sudo pip3 install lxml
```

After that you have to run the **make** command in order to build the **pyqt5-dev-tools library** so that the python code can use it properly (**make** is used to build executable libraries and programs from source code):

```
 make qt5py3
```

And finally you can run **python3 labelImg.py** and use **labelImg**.

Comment: I installed `lxml` but as expected the import error remains.

Comment: Now I noticed that there's an installation instructions, you have to run make. Try following the steps

Comment: What do you mean by `make`?

Comment: I edited my answer and included a clarification about make, please check.

Comment: Well, it didn't work. I have tried make also. The problem is with local modules/libraries so it would be unlikely `qt5py3` to cause trouble anyway.